# Spring AOP: Why @After annotation executes after @AfterThrowing in Java, AspectJ?

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

I am learning AspectJ annotations and I thought that @After annotation executes before @AfterThrowing annotation. But instead, it executes after it. Why?

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
@Order(2)
public class MyDemoLoggingAspect {

    @After("execution(* com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO.findAccounts(..))")
    public void afterFinallyFindAccountsAdvice(JoinPoint theJoinPoint) {
        
        // print out which method we are advising on
        String method = theJoinPoint.getSignature().toShortString();
        System.out.println("\n=====>>> Executing @After (finally) on method: " 
                            + method);
    
    }
    
    @AfterThrowing(
            pointcut="execution(* com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO.findAccounts(..))",
            throwing="theExc")
    public void afterThrowingFindAccountsAdvice(
                    JoinPoint theJoinPoint, Throwable theExc) {
        
        // print out which method we are advising on
        String method = theJoinPoint.getSignature().toShortString();
        System.out.println("\n=====>>> Executing @AfterThrowing on method: " + method);
        
        // log the exception
        System.out.println("\n=====>>> The exception is: " + theExc);
    
    }
    
    @AfterReturning(
            pointcut="execution(* com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO.findAccounts(..))",
            returning="result")
    public void afterReturningFindAccountsAdvice(
                    JoinPoint theJoinPoint, List<Account> result) {
        
        // print out which method we are advising on 
        String method = theJoinPoint.getSignature().toShortString();
        System.out.println("\n=====>>> Executing @AfterReturning on method: " + method);
                
        // print out the results of the method call
        System.out.println("\n=====>>> result is: " + result);
        
        // let's post-process the data ... let's modify it :-)
        
        // convert the account names to uppercase
        convertAccountNamesToUpperCase(result);

        System.out.println("\n=====>>> result is: " + result);
        
    }

    private void convertAccountNamesToUpperCase(List<Account> result) {

        // loop through accounts

        for (Account tempAccount : result) {
            
            // get uppercase version of name
            String theUpperName = tempAccount.getName().toUpperCase();
            
            // update the name on the account
            tempAccount.setName(theUpperName);
        }

    }

    @Before("com.luv2code.aopdemo.aspect.LuvAopExpressions.forDaoPackageNoGetterSetter()")
    public void beforeAddAccountAdvice(JoinPoint theJoinPoint) {
        
        System.out.println("\n=====>>> Executing @Before advice on method");    
        
        // display the method signature
        MethodSignature methodSig = (MethodSignature) theJoinPoint.getSignature();
        
        System.out.println("Method: " + methodSig);
        
        // display method arguments
        
        // get args
        Object[] args = theJoinPoint.getArgs();
        
        // loop thru args
        for (Object tempArg : args) {
            System.out.println(tempArg);
            
            if (tempArg instanceof Account) {
                
                // downcast and print Account specific stuff
                Account theAccount = (Account) tempArg;
                
                System.out.println("account name: " + theAccount.getName());
                System.out.println("account level: " + theAccount.getLevel());                              

            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Output example:

=====>>> Logging to Cloud in async fashion

=====>>> Executing @Before advice on method
Method: List com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO.findAccounts(boolean)
true

=====>>> Performing API analytics

=====>>> Executing @AfterThrowing on method: AccountDAO.findAccounts(..)

=====>>> The exception is: java.lang.RuntimeException: No soup for you!!!

=====>>> Executing @After (finally) on method: AccountDAO.findAccounts(..)

Main Program ... caught exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: No soup for you!!!

### Main Program: AfterThrowingDemoApp

null

Comment: I am also learning from the same udemy tutorial, I think the example showing from the tut behave in a different way then the current version of  the libraries we are having now.
The same issue appears on the success case too, @ AfterReturning is run BEFORE  @ After

Comment: Oh, this explains a lot.  But what to do after this course? I don't even know what a project I can do for myself.  I've decided to learn other things. Anyway I think that I've lost my way in programming and nobody know what to advice me what to do((

Comment: As the tutorial advises, you can use AOP for logging performance of the targeting methods, using AROUND pointcut . Other use case like logging, input validation, pre or post processing of input and output argements, etc.

Comment: All Chad derby tutorial guys face this dilemna.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to your question is in your log statements itself. After Advice is equivalent to a finally block

=====>>> Executing @After (finally) on method: AccountDAO.findAccounts(..)

Before , AfterThrowing and After are analogus to the following java code.

```
public void advice() {
    before();
    try {
        joinPoint();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        afterThrowing();
    } finally {
        after();
    }
}

private void before() {
    System.out.println("Before");
}

private void after() {
    System.out.println("After");
    
}

private void afterThrowing() {
    System.out.println("After throwing");
    
}

public void joinPoint() {
    System.out.println("Performing API analytics");
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Hope this helps

References

[Finally block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

[After(Finally) Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-advice-after-finally)

Comment: Thank you very much for you explanation

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63432990/1082681) for some documentation links.